# Extension bundle meaning in OSGi framework

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm developing an OSGi based application. While documenting myself on the features of the OSGi framework I stumbled on the **extension bundle** concept. Citing the R4 specification ([OSGi R4](https://osgi.org/download/r4v41/r4.core.pdf)):

> Extension bundles can deliver optional parts of the Framework
>   implementation or provide functionality that must reside on the boot
>   class path. These packages cannot be provided by the normal
>   import/export mechanisms. Boot class path extensions are necessary
>   because certain package implementations assume that they are on the
>   boot class path or are required to be available to all clients. An
>   example of a boot class path extension is an implementation of
>   java.sql such as JSR 169

Probably it's just me being stupid, but I'm having difficulties on understanding the concept. I have several questions:

1. From what I understood it seems that extension bundles are doing the **same** work of `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` and `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation`(i.e. `com.sun.*` or `sun.*`). Am I right? If not, what are the differences between them?
2. Can you show me a real use case scenario for extension bundles? Something that says: "you can't do it unless you use extension bundles!" [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rotty3000/1291842/raw/c9fdd04c080367771ea3a5858ab7c13af0fbce4e/gistfile1.txt) someone already tried to provide an example for extension bundles but (at least for me) it seems one can achieve the same result by tweaking `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` and `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation`;

I know there is already [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787985/apache-felix-what-are-extension-bundles) but to me it didn't fully hit the point.

Thanks for all kind replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extension bundles can be used to override any class, even java.lang classes.

You might want to trace when System.gc() is called for example (e.g. write a stack trace to a log file)

Comment: What? Is it so powerful? Can you show me a code example? And, by *any class*, does is it include also a class inside a bundle private implementation? Even singleton bundles?

Comment: @Koldar Yes the boot class path is always chosen first. The only way to override something already in the boot class path is to add it as an extension.

Comment: wow it seems really powerful! But doesn't it break modularity? One might think that implementations can't be accessed in any way but via extensions one can "poke his nose" into implementations details! (BTW please add a code example in your answer and I'll gladly accept your answer)

Comment: @Koldar it's definitely a solution of last resort. Sometimes there isn't a better way.

Comment: Extension bundles cannot override `java.` classes.  `ClassLoader.defineClass` unconditionally throws when attempting to define a `java.` class, so it is not possible to implement overriding via class loader delegation.  Only `-Xbootclasspath` can override `java.` classes.

Comment: @Brett Kail, ok now seems a little more legit

Comment: @BrettKail Is basically correct. Extension bundles can only replace `java.*` classes if they are on the boot classpath, so to support an extension bundle with `extension:=bootclasspath` the Framework implementation would have to find a way to put the contents on the boot classpath. It may or may not be able to do this, depending on the Java implementation. Remember that -Xbootclasspath is a non-standard option of the Sun/Oracle JDK and OpenJDK, not necessarily other Javas.

Comment: @NeilBartlett in particular, it won't be available in Oracle Java 9. ;)

Comment: Further, I would say that in 16+ years of using OSGi, I have never had to create Extension bundles with `extension:=bootclasspath`. It's there to support very specific edge cases.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I used it to trace why System gc was being called and it was the DGC. Not needed in production I would hope.

Comment: In case you're wondering how `extension:=bootclasspath` works at all, it would typically be some kind of script or launcher app that runs before the JVM. Changing the Framework Extension bundles is expected to cause a JVM restart, which would also be handled by such a script.

Comment: @NeilBartlett it has to be set on the command line but the boot class path is something the JVM does at runtime.